# How to add elements of list to another list?

Tags: java, sql, list, collections

I have two sql queries, which returning lists. My code:

```
List<String> list = em.createNativeQuery(query1).getResultList();
list.addAll(em.createNativeQuery(query2).getResultList());
```

What I have: List with two sublists - sublist from query1 and sublist from query2.

What I need: One list with all elements from query1 and query2.

Any idea?

---

Problem was in first sql query. Result was adding in object array, therefore addAll method not solves my problem.

Comment: write a query which will return SQL `query1 UNION query2`.

Comment: `list.addAll(em.createNativeQuery(query2).getResultList());` will give you list from query1 and query2. Isn't it?

Comment: query1: "select mobile_phone, password, first_name, last_name from Accounts where mobile_phone='" + phone + "'"

query2: "select name from Mails where user_id=(select id from Accounts where mobile_phone='" + phone +"\')"

Comment: Your code seems correct according to your requirement.....If you are concerned about duplicates then use `Set`..

Comment: Try this query:
select mobile_phone, password, first_name, last_name, name from Accounts join Mails on Accounts.id = Mails.user_id where mobile_phone='" + phone + "'";

Comment: @anubhava
In result list I have list of Objects[], which consists of String variables, and String (in database only one result for that query).

Comment: do you get a `ClasCastException` since i expect `getResultList()` to return a `List<Object>`

Comment: @BalazsGunics Now I have list with one sublist, but I need in one list without sublists.

Comment: @MarcoForberg No. Program working without exceptions

Comment: @MarcoForberg you shouldn't use addAll(), as you said, you have 1 sublist, make that sublist "THE" list, and no problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

addAll() will work. code is correct to get data from both the query

Comment: If code is worked, than for what I was creating the new topic?

Comment: one example that I would like to share that worked for me                   
List<String[]> dataList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
dataList.addAll(getDataList(qry1));
dataList.addAll(getDataList(qry2));

Answer (score 5):

I created a similar situation to test what you were saying. Obviously I do not have access to your specific database to query, so I just focused on the point of your question; the `List` combination.

```
List<String> foods = new ArrayList<String>(); //this is analogous with the list returned from your first query
foods.add("Beef");
foods.add("Chicken");
System.out.println("foods(query1):  "+foods);

List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<String>(); //this is analogous with the list returned from your second query
fruits.add("Apple");
fruits.add("Peach");
fruits.add("Pear");
System.out.println("fruits(query2):  "+fruits);


foods.addAll(fruits); //this combines the two lists (your two queries)
System.out.println("foods(after combination of queries):  "+foods);
```

The output was:

```
foods(query1):  [Beef, Chicken]
fruits(query2):  [Apple, Peach, Pear]
foods(after combination of queries):  [Beef, Chicken, Apple, Peach, Pear]
```

My only thought as to why you are not getting that result would be that one of your queries is not returning anything...  I would recommend trying to print out each list prior to adding them together as I did above and see if one is empty.

Comment: Try to run with debugger and see on the list values.

Comment: The values on the lists in debug are identical to the values printed...Are you getting a different result running my code on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to create list of lists, i.e.:

`List<List<String>> listOfLists = ...;`

You cannot store both strings and lists of strings in the same list that is defined this way. If you indeed want to do this you should just define `List<Object>` and you will be able to store there elements of any type. However it is highly not recommended. Generics have been introduced to java to prevent such usage at compile time.

So, what you probably really want is to creatate list of list of strings and then perform queries that return lists of strings and add result to the first list:

```
List<List<String>> list = new LinkedList<List<String>>();
list.addAll(em.createNativeQuery(query1).getResultList());
list.addAll(em.createNativeQuery(query1).getResultList());
```

BTW this approach is not recommended too. Typically if you want to create n-dimensional collection where n>1 you probably should create yet another container class that holds collection and other stuff and then create 1-dimensional collection that stores instances of this class.

Comment: No. I want to create ONE list without sublists. I want to merge lists from two queries to one.